# What is a proper way to inject an object that needs parameter inside servlets in java ee?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, cdi

I'm making a java application using jsp and servlets. I want to store some data in HTTP session but I want to use the session only inside a `RepositoryImpl` class. I also have an interface called `Repository` with methods like `addItem()` and `getData()`. So my `RepositoryImpl` class implements these methods and uses HTTP session to store the data.

I want to inject the `RepositoryImpl` class into different servlets to use it as an instance of `Repository` interface. The problem is I don't know how to pass the `session` to the `RepostioryImpl` instance with `ejb` or `cdi`. What is the best way to handle my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if i understand.

You want to store data in session, like a shopping cart?

If you want to store in session an entire object you can set it in a usebean.

```
<jsp:useBean id="objectname" scope="session" class="com.mypackage.myclass"/>
```

This way you can call the object and it's methods wherever the usebean is.

I hope this could help.